# ERR_CACHE_MISS error in codeigniter when click backbutton

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a small web application using codeigniter.But sometimes when I click back button this error message display. What Should Ido to avoid this matter?
Confirm Form Resubmission

This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
ERR_CACHE_MISS
This is part of my main controller

```
<?php

ob_start();
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Home extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct()
         {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->load->library('session');
              $this->load->helper('form');
              $this->load->helper('url','html');
              $this->load->helper('html');
              $this->load->database();
              $this->load->library('form_validation');


              $this->load->model('Login_model');
              $this->load->model('Select');
              $this->load->model('ProjectEmployees');
              $this->load->model('Employee_model');
              $this->load->model('Welcome_model','welcome');
              $this->load->model('Welcome_model4','welcome4'); 
              $this->load->model('Welcome_modelPI','welcomePI');




         }
         function index()
      { 


        $this->load->view('login_view');


      }

      function logout()
      {
        // destroy session
            $data = array('login' => '', 'uname' => '', 'uid' => '');
            $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Home/index');
      }


    public function MyHome()
    {   
        $this->load->view('template/navigation');
            $this->load->view('template/sideNav');
            $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('profile_view2');
         $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*It's because you Expiring the Page & not sending the Cache Header to Browser. That's why Browser not Caching those pages and while you hitting back Browser displaying ERR_CACHE_MISS instead of your html view..*

***ERR_CACHE_MISS (Screen):***

[image]

> 1. Make sure you are not Sending Expire Cache Header
> 2. Make sure your page not prevent by Browser Cache
> 3. Check your Response Header in Browser Net Panel, to See what Header
>      being passed by Server
> 4. Check if your are using `$this->output->set_header()` in your
>      code/controller/hook.

***Here are some CodeIgniter Cache Expire Header Code Example..***

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
$this->output->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.singh. Where should I put this code? I haven't use $this->output->set_header() this in myanyof controller

Comment: @Dushee Can you share your view and controller code here to understand the problem..

Comment: Mr.Singh I add my controller. I am sorry to say I don't know what caching is. Your help is really really appreciated

Comment: @Dushee, well your controller seems fine. It very hard to guess where & why code is breaking without full information. but still you can give a chance. Check if you are using redirection for login and not login user, check if you setup a method without any output. check if ERR_CACHE_MISS page url has any output or view to display.. you can share the screenshot and browser url and step how and when its breaking..

Comment: Mr.Singh my small web application have forms to submit data and tables to view those data. This error occured only form submission views.Other views works well

Comment: Mr.Singh this popup message appear "" The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?""

Comment: You can give a try by using header('Cache-Control: no cache'); //disable validation of form by the browser in your controller constructor. If not then you have to share your all controller code and view code here to resolve your problem.. I will share a small form submission for with you to check whether its working or not.

Comment: You can get a sample login form and controller from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742006/codeigniter-jquery-validator-library-not-work/44747674#44747674

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147556/discussion-between-dushee-and-neeraj-singh).